# Rails carrierwave and minimagick allow landscape image only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, minimagick

Is it way to validate image orientation on image upload?
I want that user can upload only landscape image.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader

validate :check_landscape

def check_landscape
  if photo.width<photo.height
     errors.add :photo, "is not a landscape." 
     puts "Error ! not a Landscape Image"
  else if photo.width>photo.height
     puts " Landscape Image"
  end
  end
end
```

if you are looking for active_storage has_many_attached

```
has_many_attached :images


validate: active_storage_many_images

 def active_storage_many_images
    images.each do |image|

    image.blob.analyze unless image.blob.analyzed?
    width = image.blob.metadata[:width]
    height = image.blob.metadata[:height]

    if width<height
      errors.add :image, "Additional images are not landscape"
      puts "ACTIVE STORAGE IMAGE ERROR !!"
    end
  end
 end
```

Comment: A more detailed explanation of your code would make it easier for the question asker to understand what you are trying to convey. I would suggest going back an adding additional detail as to why this is the right answer for the question. It would also provide greater clarity for other users who may be experiencing similar problems.

Comment: It's no special code. Only simple ulploader, but I need to raise errore when portrait photo was ploaded

Answer (score 1):

So all you need here is EXIF metadata of an image. I saw a gem that helps us to get metadata from the image that we uploaded, seems like it can help you in this case

https://github.com/gzigzigzeo/carrierwave-meta

Basically, we can get the size of image_size then create a validation rely on it.